# make this code faster - vectorize for each row in dataframe?

Tags: r, performance, vectorization, apply

I have the following code that makes a graph using the package rgraphviz by going through each row of a data frame and adding an edge to the graph.

This is a bit slow, and I suspect it can be faster without the for each loop, and to use by() or apply() instead. Can anyone provide the code on how to do that?

The end goal is to make the code faster, so other suggestions are also welcome.

```
gR <- new("graphNEL", nodes = nodes, edgemode = "directed")
#add edges for each row in df
for (j in (1:nrow(df))) {
   gR <- addEdge(df[j,2], df[j,1], gR, 1)
}
```

Comment: How about this? `by(nrow(df),function(x){addEdge(df[x,2], df[x,1], gR, 1)})`

Comment: From `?addEdge()`, "Both 'from' and 'to' can be vectors", so maybe `gr = addEdge(df[,2], df[,1], gR, 1)`

Comment: @User7598 - that looks good but I get this error when I run it: Error in unique.default(x, nmax = nmax) : 
  unique() applies only to vectors